# How to I reference an array member in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Given this array in Ruby:

```
myarray = [name: "John", age: 35]
```

How do I refer to the age?

I tried `myarray[:age]` but got an error `can't convert Symbol into Integer`

Update:

I was trying to simplify my question by extracting what I thought my problem is.  I may not understand completely.

I'm experimenting with [Dashing](http://dashing.io/) and trying to send a number to a meter widget.  I've created a variable, 'response_raw' and am trying to send it in the third send event.  Here's my code:

```
SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do
    # Get checks
    url = "https://#{CGI::escape user}:#{CGI::escape password}@api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks"
    `enter code here`response = RestClient.get(url, {"App-Key" => api_key})
    response = JSON.parse(response.body, :symbolize_names => true)

    if response[:checks]
      checks = response[:checks].map { |check|
        if check[:status] == 'up'
          state = 'up'
          last_response_time = "#{check[:lastresponsetime]}ms"
          response_raw = check[:lastresponsetime]
        else
          state = 'down'
          last_response_time = "DOWN"
          response_raw = 0
        end

        { name: check[:name], state: state, lastRepsonseTime: last_response_time, pt: response_raw }
      }
    else
      checks = [name: "pingdom", state: "down", lastRepsonseTime: "-", pt: 0]
    end

    checks.sort_by { |check| check['name'] }
    send_event('pingdom', { checks: checks })
    send_event('pingdom-meter', { value:  checks[:pt] })                                                                                                                        
  end
```

Comment: Your code looks more like a Ruby, rather than CoffeeScript.

Comment: And "can't convert Symbol into Integer" is a Ruby error, not a CoffeeScript error.

Answer (score 1):

In CoffeeScript `[name: "John", age: 35]` is an array containing single object with two properties (`name` and `age`).

Here is how it'll look in plain JavaScript:

```
myarray = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 35
  }
];
```

So, answering your question, to access an `age` you should take the first element of an array and then reference an `age` property:

```
myarray[0].age
```

or

```
myarray[0]['age']
```

But, judging from your  question, your're probably using wrong data structure. Why don't you want to use a plain object instead of an array?

```
person = name: "John", age: 35
console.log "#{person.name}'s age is #{person.age}"
```

## Update

It looks like your question is actually about Ruby and not about CoffeeScript. Though, my answer will remain the same.

To access an `age` you should take the first element of an array and then reference an `age` property:

```
myarray[0][:age]
```

Since `myarray` is an array, Ruby expects an integer index, but you're giving it symbol `:age` instead.

Comment: I just added the code I'm actually working with.  I was trying to simplify my question, but that may have not been accurate.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: The OP is confused, all the code in the question is Ruby, not CoffeeScript. The error message is also from Ruby.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, I got it. But before OP edited his question, it looked pretty much like CoffeeScript.

Comment: Interestingly, the answer is still more or less right modulo "object"/"hash".

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out with Leonid's help.  Thank you.

I changed:

```
send_event('pingdom-meter', { value:  checks[:pt] })
```

to

```
send_event('pingdom-meter', { value:  checks[0][:pt] })
```

Comment: Why are you sticking the hash in an array in the first place?

Comment: I'm just staying within the data structure the original developer used.